# SSIS The expression for variable 'Variable' failed evaluation. There was an error in the expression

Tags: ssis

So here we have an error I keep getting in my SSIS package but I can't see what is wrong with the statement. I have even tried another sql statement from a project that works and it still raises the error.

The system is VS 2005 running 64 bit debugger, on XP machine. The project has amongst other things a script task then a sql task, the script task outputs the month value to a variable (Dts.Variables("monthName").Value = month), which I then use to create dynamic table name in SQL statement. I haven't got to the excel sheet bit yet as I am trying to get the sql task stage working.

So i have a variable at package level called SQLTableCreate, and in that I have the properties set to:

- Evaluate as Expression = true
- Expression = "Create Table "+ @[user::monthName]+"(`Column1` DATETIME,`Column2` NVARCHAR(255),`Column3` NVARCHAR(255),`Column4` NVARCHAR(255),`Column5` NVARCHAR(255),`Column6` NVARCHAR(255),`Column7` NVARCHAR(255),`Column8` NVARCHAR(255),`Column9` NVARCHAR(255),`Column10` NVARCHAR(255))"

And when I build the package I get:

> Nonfatal errors occurred while saving the package:
>   Error at Package: The variable "user::monthName" was not found in the Variables collection. The variable might not exist in the correct scope.
>   Error at Package: Attempt to parse the expression ""Create Table "+ @[user::MonthName]+"(`Column1` DATETIME,`Column2` NVARCHAR(255),`Column3` NVARCHAR(255),`Column4` NVARCHAR(255),`Column5` NVARCHAR(255),`Column6` NVARCHAR(255),`Column7` NVARCHAR(255),`Column8` NVARCHAR(255),`Column9` NVARCHAR(255),`Column10` NVARCHAR(255))"
>   " failed and returned error code 0xC00470A6. The expression cannot be parsed. It might contain invalid elements or it might not be well-formed. There may also be an out-of-memory error.Error at Package: The expression for variable "SQLTableCreate" failed evaluation. There was an error in the expression.

There is also a default SQL statement for the variable SQLTableCreate, which uses the current excel connection manager table name. When I put my dynamic statement in the expression section of properties it fills the value and valuetype property of the SQLTableCreate variable with the message:

> The expression for variable "SQLTableCreate" failed evaluation. There was an error in the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly as the error says

> The variable "user::monthName" was not found in the Variables collection

Things in SSIS are case sensitive and Variables are one of those things. Make your expression

- "Create Table "+ @[User::monthName]+"(Column1 DATETIME,Column2 NVARCHAR(255),Column3 NVARCHAR(255),Column4 NVARCHAR(255),Column5 NVARCHAR(255),Column6 NVARCHAR(255),Column7 NVARCHAR(255),Column8 NVARCHAR(255),Column9 NVARCHAR(255),Column10 NVARCHAR(255))"

Also, I hope this table design is just a sample and not real. Lack of column names and strong data types is technical debt you don't need to incur at this stage.

Comment: Sorry I noticed that before and changed that variable name from MonthName to monthName and it still doesn't work. Yes the design is just a sample of my query.

Comment: The namespace, User is also case sensitive

Comment: That's the fix I needed thanks. Sheesh sittin here with glazed eyes trying to figure out what's wrong! didn't realise that was case-sensitive.